# Whats the meaning of following jvm parameters?

Tags: java, parameters, jvm

Whats the difference between the following jvm parameters?

`-Xms2048M` : its min heap space allocated for jvm

`-Xmx2048M` : its max heap space allocated for jvm

`-XX:NewSize=512M` : what does this do?

`-XX:MaxNewSize=512M` : what does this do?

Comment: Why not look into documentaion --- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html

Comment: Hi Balwinder, As i gone through the link, i find newsize and xms are same. Then in our project they had set both the parameters as mentioned above. so i want to know what will be the heap size of our application?

Comment: Nope they are not. It clearly states that -- "The -Xms and -Xmx parameters define the minimum and maximum heap sizes" & "The NewSize and MaxNewSize parameters control the new generation’s minimum and maximum size". You need to learn about old generation and new generation sizes too. Have a look at http://www.journaldev.com/2856/java-jvm-memory-model-and-garbage-collection-monitoring-tuning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are good enough in understanding the young generation and old generation GC then you can able to understand it easily.

To set the lower and upper bound for the size of younger generation we need to use -XX:NewSize and XX:MaxNewSize.

Consider young generation is an part of heap so the best practice is to set the size (XX:MaxNewSize) not more than the older generation.

For performance reasons you can set the initial size XX:NewSize but you need to know the rate of young objects collected.

[GC Tuning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html)
[Young Vs Old](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue115.html)

Comment: One confusion, in our application i see                                                     - Xms2048M
-Xmx2048M   and also -XX:NewSize=512M
-XX:MaxNewSize=512M, what does this mean? as per the link,  i understand heap size  as 2gb, where young gen as 5gb. is this correct intialization for an application? Because young gen is part of heap space, as i see heap space is less than young gen space... Please help me in understanding.

Comment: 512M is half of the gb, is this typo ?